# Extract form variable in AJAX response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

All,

I have a Jquery ajax request calling out a URL. The ajax response I receive is an HTML form with one hidden variable in it. As soon as my ajax request is successful, I would like to retrieve the value of the hidden variabl. How do I do that?

```
Example:

html_response for the AJAX call is : 
<html><head></head><body><form name="frmValues"><input type="hidden" 
name="priceValue" value="100"></form></body></html>


$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/abc/xyz/getName?id="+101,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html_response)
        {
            //Extract form variable "priceValue" from html_response
            //Alert the variable data.                                 
        }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html_response you get will be a string. As such, if you happen to know exactly what the page will look like, you can just search the text using `indexOf`.

...But that solution is messy and error prone. Alternatively, you could create a new HTML element (like a `div`), put your response html in there, and then obtain the hidden variable as you would access any normal html element.

For example:

```
var tempDiv = $("<div/>");
tempDiv.append(html_response);
var myValue = tempDiv.find("input[name='priceValue']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create JQuery object:

```
var form = $(html_response);
```

Then get your input PriceValue using JQuery selectors & traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it with `$(html_response).find("input[name='priceValue']").val();`